# How to get Latex-style output from sympy in Spyder IPython console?

Tags: python, latex, anaconda, sympy, spyder

I using sympy in Spyder and would like Latex output for symbolic computations in IPython console. I have installed Spyder trough Anaconda and created a separate environment. At first I was getting only ASCII pretty printer output, but after installing matplotlib in that environment I can also get nicer graphical output.

```
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing() 
integrate(x)
```

When I execute the above code in IPython, I get graphical (image) output x^2/2, but not latex. This means sympy did not find Latex, and used next best thing, which is matplotlib in my case, right ?

I’m not sure how to proceed to get Latex-style output, can I install some package trough Anaconda to automatically upgrade to Latex output, or I have to manually install some Latex distribution on my operating system like MiKTeX ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I execute the above code in IPython, I get graphical (image) output x^2/2, but not latex. This means sympy did not find Latex, and used next best thing, which is matplotlib in my case, right ?

That's correct.

> I’m not sure how to proceed to get Latex-style output, can I install some package trough Anaconda to automatically upgrade to Latex output, or I have to manually install some Latex distribution on my operating system like MiKTeX ?

There's no other package in Anaconda (besides `matplotlib`) that gives you Latex output, which means (as you correctly guessed) that you need to install Miktex to get it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. It seems I'll have to use matplotlib rendering for some time before installing MikTEX (Because of formal reasons). 
One thing I find clumsy in matplotlib rendering is no space between symbols. For example defining expression expr = (x*Ds + k*y*Ic) where x, Ds, k, y, Ic are symbols renders as Dsx + Icky. Do you know Is there a way to improve readability here with matplotlib rendering and if latex output has the same problem?

Comment: Correction, in my last post above in expr there should be multiply sign * between the x, Ds and k, y symbols. It seems it gets deleted from the comment even though I did enter it.

Comment: Matplotlib's Latex implementation is very limited and simple, so I'd suggest you to install Miktex right away if you want to see well rendered formulas all the time.