# How to activate and deactivate print formats in sympy?

Tags: printing, format, sympy

I try to use the output format of sympy in spyder in a script. I would like to understand how to activate and deactivate the format without changing the console to reset everything.

The format I would like to achieve is something like this: ["[Out2]" is what I'd like to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVhe7.png)

**Code suggestions which don't work for me**

I have tried these so far:

```
import sympy as sym
x= sym.symbols("x")

sym.init_session(quiet=True)
print(sym.Integral(sym.sqrt(1/x),x))
```

or

```
from IPython.display import display
display(sym.Integral(sym.Integral(sym.sqrt(1/x),x))
```

or

```
sym.init_printing()
sym.pprint(sym.Integral(sym.sqrt(1/x),x))
```

I just can achieve something like this:
[this format is not what I try to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVmIE.png)

Comment: That's latex output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915513/how-to-get-latex-style-output-from-sympy-in-spyder-ipython-console

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a bit of a weird phenomenon. Sometimes it prints a latex output and sometime some other format which name is unknown for me. I haven't installed MikTex. So far it seems to work out for me with this code:       from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=(True))

import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols("x")
display(sym.Integral(x,x))